# 2-dimensional Tuple vs OrderedDict vs List of Tuples

Tags: python, python-3.5

Let's say I have an immutable list of key-value pairs

```
"banana" : "yellow"
"apple" : "red"
"kiwi" : "green"
```

The only thing that matters is the ordering, I will never need to access an item directly by its key, only iterate through them in order and receive a pair of values.

So, considering what is said above, which is more recommended, a 2d tuple, a dictionary or a list of tuples?

```
from collections import OrderedDict    

two_d_tuple = (
('banana', 'yellow'),
('apple', 'red'),
('kiwi', 'green')
)

list_of_tuples = [
('banana', 'yellow'),
('apple', 'red'),
('kiwi', 'green')
]

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(list_of_tuples)
```

Comment: The answer is in the question - right at the beginning : "I have a list of key:value pairs". Semantically it's a list of tuples.

Comment: By the way, `2d_tuple` is not a valid python identifier.  If you change the name, stackoverflow's syntax highlighter will probably be more happy with your post :-)

Comment: @mgilson forgot that, fixed!

Comment: Check the definition of all, you will get the answer. Each type has its own set of feature and use-case. In short, use the one which best fits you, and for that you need to check each one out :)

Comment: @Mojimi, you want ascending alphabetical order based on key or value?

Comment: @Imiguelvargasf order of creation, forgot to mention the list is immutable

Comment: On python 3.6, you can just use a dict..

Comment: Are there any other restrictions? Performance or space?

Comment: @ppasler no hardware restriction, although its for a server so performance its the priority

Comment: @wim -- I'm pretty sure that the "On python3.6, you can just use a dict" is the sort of advice that would make the python developers sad if they saw you promoting that.  Python dictionaries are unordered.  The fact that python3.6 dictionaries are ordered is an [implementation detail](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) that happened to allow other optimizations...

Comment: @mgilson  Yeah, it was more of a "fun fact" than an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing an ordered collection of key/value pairs. This is precisely what `collections.OrderedDict` is for, so I would definitely use that.

Your tuple of tuples and your list of tuples are attempts at building up a complicated data structure from more basic ones. This is of course fine, but why not use the data structure already build for the job? This is what [batteries included](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0206/#batteries-included-philosophy) is all about.

Also, because `collections.OrderedDict` accurately reflects the data structure you are describing, more advanced features (e.g. iterating over the keys only) is already implemented, while you would have to re-implement such features for your other two "home made" data structures.

Comment: I'm not sure if building an ordered dict brings too much overhead, if OP won't use the keys to get the values.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't need to do any lookup based on keys, then I'd use a sequence of tuples.  There no reason to create the dictionary here -- And you need to create the sequence of tuples to construct the dict anyway.

If you do need to lookup items based on the keys, then I'd use the `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 3):

The way to decide what is the best format is by looking at performance times...

The performance time is calculated as the difference between the time right before `OrderedDict` is executed, and the time right after it's executed; as the example bellow shows:

```
def compare_time(list_of_tuples):
   start=datetime.datetime.now()
   ordered_dict = OrderedDict(list_of_tuples)
   return datetime.datetime.now()-start
```

From the example it is pretty clear, that based on the shown list, `list_of_tuples` will take the least amount of time.

```
ori@sonoma:~$ python3 stack.py 
dict 0:00:00.000016
two_d_tuple 0:00:00.000014
list_of_tuples 0:00:00.000009
```

With that said, I'm not sure what order you want the output to be in, because each type of key-value pair returns a different ordering...

```
dict OrderedDict([('banana', 'yellow'), ('kiwi', 'green'), ('apple', 'red')]) 
two_d_tuple OrderedDict([('banana', 'yellow'), ('apple', 'red'), ('kiwi', 'green')]) 
list_of_tuples OrderedDict([('banana', 'yellow'), ('apple', 'red'), ('kiwi', 'green')])
```